# Highlight text and a polygon shape on an image simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to achieve an effect similar to [this site](http://www.kpf.com/projectlist.asp?T=4):

[image]

only instead of the mouseover function putting a border around the corresponding image, I want to simply highlight different parts of the image by drawing a polygon with defined coordinates over the image.

I have a test of my site up at:

http://perfectdays.ca/image-map/

I used a plugin called ImageMapper in Wordpress to create the image map as you see it on the site.  Right now, when you mouseover the arms, for example, the arm regions on the image are highlighted.

I cannot figure out how to a)have the corresponding text on the left get highlighted when you mouseover the arms, or vice versa (and more importantly), have the arms highlight when you mouseover the text "Full Arms."

There was a somewhat similar post called [Javascript Newbie: How to highlight text and image in different divs on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544998/javascript-newbie-how-to-highlight-text-and-image-in-different-divs-on-mouseove).

However I cannot figure out how to adapt that to include the highlighting of certain parts of the image without using the plugin mentioned above.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to put this in your area tags?

```
onmouseover="highlight(this.id);"
```

Then you can just make a simple javascript function that changes the class of the corresponding link.