# Highlight image area from text link in WordPress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dictionary, hyperlink, highlight

I'm not a coder at all and I've lost two days try to doing this! Hope someone could kindly help me...

I would like to highlight some area shape on my image map (prepared with Fireworks) not only when hover on it but also by hovering on a separate text link. I've tried some plugins for Wordpress but no one does this.

I can do what I need (using jQuery plugin "maphilight") in a [static html page](http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/map_highlight_test.html) but the same code doesn't work in [the WordPress page](http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/test-imgmap). Only for testing I have put the needed  links on the header.php (I don't know how to load scripts dynamically only in the page that use them).

My question is very similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412817/2978746) but have no solution yet.

Many many thanks to anybody that could help me. :-)

Regards. Marcella

ps. forgive my english! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have errors on your page telling you that JavaScript files could not be found.

Here are the files that could not be found:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/jquery.min'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/jquery.imagemapster.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/jquery.mappa-congressi.js'></script>
```

You could try removing the plugin and re-installing it.

The correct JavaScript references should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tommasifamilyestates.it/villa40/wp-content/plugins/marcymaps/mappa-congressi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply Jamie! Any suggestion for the right place to insert script in WordPress? I have insert the code in a custom plugin that I have made, because I don't know how to.... ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct script URLs. Are you able to add these in to the custom code area that you mentioned?

Comment: Are you able to modify the `mappa-congressi.js` file? By changing line 2 to: `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

Comment: You have another error on the page that relatives to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/10807237/1838483

Comment: I have changed line 2 as you suggest, but, sorry, I can't no understand so much the content of the question "stackoverflow.com/a/10807237/1838483"

Comment: Basically the marcymaps plugin was conflicting with JQuery. This looks better but you also have another issue with 'Sparckles' do you know what that is? The 'Sparckles' JavaScript is using an old method `browser.msie` you might be able to fix it by using Jquery migrate 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Also try disabling what ever is using 'Sparckles' to see if it will fix your map issue.

Comment: Sparckles is an effects that animates background header and came with the theme. I will try to deactivate it... Do you know another way to do what I need? The plugin is something that I did to load the js script....

Comment: You don't have any errors now, the last thing you need to check is the map image code on the page as it seams to be loading a map with the class `mapster_el map` if you remove this image you will see the working map.

Comment: Yeeeeesssss! That works! The class was added by I plugin that I've installing for try to doing the job, now I deactivated! Thanks so much! You save me! :-)